# How can I update orders in Sitecore CDP?

Tags: cdp

After I have created an order in Sitecore CDP how can this order be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orders created via stream events or Batch Import can be updated using Batch Import using the UPSERT mode, the reference_id and contact on the order is used to determine which order to update.

For details on how to create order via stream events see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sending-orders-in-sitecore-cdp.html.

For details on how to update orders using Batch Import see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sitecore-cdp-order-data-model-for-batch-api.html

Related questions:

**Can an order be updated using Stream events?**

No an order cannot be updated using Stream events.

If you are creating an order using ADD, CONFIRM and CHECKOUT using a reference_id that already exists in the CDP, a new order will be created with a duplicate reference_id.

If you are creating an order using ORDER_CHECKOUT using a reference_id that already exists in the CDP, no new order will be created.

Comment: links are no longer valid